# Custom collection sort module returning collection but not sorting

Tags: product, collection, magento-1, catalog, sorting

I've created a module that is intended to allow me to add custom sort features to my catalog pages (my product collection). For whatever reason, it returns my collection no problem but fails to honor any form of sort that I apply to it. Here is my Observer.php code

```
//File: app/code/local/MyExtensions/Attsetfilter/Model/Observer.php

<?php
class MyExtensions_Attsetfilter_Model_Observer
{
    public function load_productsby_attributesetid($observer) {
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('attribute_set_id', 'asc');
        echo "Extension is being called";
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

I know my product collection is being passed through here because if I comment out the first line of my public function ("$collction = ...") it returns nothing. I've attempted to add filters to the function like so

```
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('attribute_set_id', 'asc');
```

But it never seems to honor them. I've seen other methods of filtering a product collection such as:

```
$collection = $this->getCollection()
        ->setOrder('fieldname', 'asc')
        ->setOrder('fieldname2');
```

But that snippet won't work in my extension code either. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Here is my modules config.xml file as well:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyExtensions_Attsetfilter>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyExtensions_Attsetfilter>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <events>
    <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
      <observers>
        <product_load_before>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>MyExtensions_Attsetfilter_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>load_productsby_attributesetid</method>
        </product_load_before>
      </observers>
    </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
      <attsetfilter>
        <class>MyExtensions_Attsetfilter_Helper</class>
      </attsetfilter>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?

Yes, you observe `catalog_product_collection_load_after` instead of `catalog_product_collection_load_before`. At this point the collection is already loaded from the database.

Comment: Switching it to "before" instead of "after" seems to stop it from functioning all together.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getSelect()->order()` like this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order('attribute_set_id asc');
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't have any affect on sorting. Is it by chance supposed to be setOrder?

Comment: No, it's order().  I've had it work for me in the past when other methods failed.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks anyways. Maybe there is something I'm overlooking.

Comment: Is it not honoring ANY field that you try sort by or just that one?  Maybe `attribute_set_id` isn't a loaded attribute for the collection.  You could try `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')` prior to your sort statement to see if that helps.

Comment: Not sorting for anything. Let me try that...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.Make sure **order_no is stored as Integer in database**.That was the mistake I made.
Try this one.

`$collections=$this->getCollection()->setOrder('order_no','ASC');`